# C# Image Class to Byte Array Length Issues

Tags: c#, arrays, image

I use the `Image` class of C# to read in a file:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
```

this now means `image` has been filled with Image data.

I now convert this image to a byte array:

```
static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Now I want to convert this Byte array to a matrix array, 2d byte array:

```
var imageMatrix = byte[image.Height, image.Width];
```

When I do a for loop moving values into the new byte matrix I get a `IndexOutOfRangeException`

On inspection,

```
var isImageLengthSameAsByteLength = imageByteArray.Length == (image.Width * image.Height);
```

`isImageLengthSameAsByteLength` value is false, after looking at the values, the array length is 132442 and `(width * height)` is 130995.

So there is clearly some disparity between these. I think that there is something extra that has been encoded into the image byte array, because obviously the `height` and `width` tells you the size of the image.

Any ideas, thanks,

Comment: Images are quite often aligned on 4-byte boundaries (or similar)

Comment: each pixel corresponds to 4 bytes, so your `byte` array size should be 4 times larger than the `width*height` indeed.

Comment: @KingKing: I don't see why you'd assume that - the `Save` method uses whatever file format you tell it to, so it depends on the details of the BMP file format and what options the encoder uses. There'll be header information, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, 4 bytes is just a popular case, in fact we can set the imageformat (when using the constructor of the image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that

```
imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

will be writing exactly one byte per pixel. In fact, it's storing it in [BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) - which may well be *more* than one byte per pixel due to headers, and the fact that you can have more than 256 colours in a BMP file. Or it could be *less* than one byte per pixel if it's compressing the image.

Fundamentally, this transformation to a byte array isn't the one you want - so you'll need to work out an alternative approach. You might want to look at [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap.LockBits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if it's actually a `Bitmap` object.

Comment: That does make my life a little harder, I'm basically trying to write my own compression algorithm for Uni coursework!

Comment: @No1_Melman: Well you could investigate whether any of the `ImageFormat` options give you data you could easily work with - so long as you understand the point of the `Save` method, basically.

Comment: I got this function from an FFT class written in C# and it makes use of LockBits, the only bit I don't get is when it starts using `byte*` and uses `byte*[0]` so it makes it seem like an array, i'll write a question on it and link it here!

Comment: see this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430114/trying-to-understand-this-image-function)